# react-dropzone загрузка картинок из превью на сервер

Tags: laravel, reactjs, redux, dropzone

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста ответ на такие вопросы:

Делаю админку на панели и есть задача сделать CRUD постов на реакте.

Для работы с загрузкой картинок выбрал react-dropzone

И настроил его так, что картинки отправляются на сервер при нажатии кнопки submit, 
т.е. не загружаются при дропе сразу, а только при сохранении поста отправляются вместе с остальными данными поста.

При реализации функционала редактирования поста - нужно отобразить ранее загруженные картинки в дропзоне - это тоже не сложно.
Но вот их же тоже надо отправлять потом на сервер при сохранении, а они есть только как preview в компоненте, а как файлы не отправляются почему-то.

Вопрос 1: вообще возможно сделать отправку тех картинок, которые есть в превью на сервер повторно?
Вопрос 2: как это сделать?

Пробовал просто подставлять в превью ссылку на картинку - и тогда превью нормально отображается.

Также пробовал fetch скачивание картинки и перевод ее в буфер. но правда не смог в base 64 подставить нормально.

Comment: а зачем их повторно отправлять если они уже лежат на сервере, или я что-то не понял?

Comment: Хочется реализовать логику более просто, без сверок, что было ранее, что стало потом. 
Хочется просто при сохранении поста в редактировании - стереть все ранее загруженные и залить все новые пришедшие.